# compile error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans, 3d, java-3d

I run my first program with 3D graphics in java but it has one exception
please help me in solve that.
this is my code:

```
public class Test extends Applet {

public Test() {
    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
                    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
                    group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
                    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
                    universe.addBranchGraph(group);


}


}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   new Test();
}

}
```

and this is it's error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
        at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
        at test1.Test.<init>(Test.java:26)
        at test1.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some bits of Java3D require native libraries to work.

See [here for a description of what's necessary](http://www.filsa.net/2008/07/17/eclipse-java3d-and-javalibrarypath/).

Comment: this is for eclipse in net beans i didn't find where i do that.

Comment: still i can't run program and has same error please help me in solving this problem.i don't understand native libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you trying to import a library that doesn't exist, or is in the wrong location.

Comment: I download j3d library from internet and i'm sure it exist!

Comment: Then it's not in your classpath when you run.

Comment: Check where you downloaded it to. Is it in your JDK files? Probably needs to be with the rest of your jdk lib files

Comment: i add it in this address C:\NetBean 6.9.1\java\modules\ext it's true?

Comment: @mehdi Check this link: (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html). Are any of your J3D methods declared native when they don't need to or shouldn't be?